# ssh -p 29418 throws this error: Permission denied (publickey). but without port 29418 it works fine

Tags: git, port, gerrit, review

I have seen plenty of solutions on this particular error on the web. However, none of them seem to correctly answer my question - It works fine without the port 29418, why? Not sure what am I missing.

**ERROR CASE:**

```
$ ssh -p 29418 gerrit@9.126.191.111  
gerrit@9.126.191.111: Permission denied (publickey).
```

**SUCCESS CASE:**

```
$ ssh gerrit@9.126.191.111
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-21-generic x86_64)
 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
374 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
*** System restart required ***
Last login: Sat Aug 11 18:00:28 2018 from 9.77.121.154
gerrit@gerrserv:~$
```

I checked to see if there is any option for ssh-keygen to speficy port. But I did not see any such. Of course, I am facing this issue while trying to fix an issue with `git review -s` command failure where scp is not picking up the port 29418 and throwing the usage error for scp:

```
$ git review

Problems encountered installing commit-msg hook
The following command failed with exit code 1
"scp -P gerrit@9.126.191.111:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg"
-----------------------
usage: scp [-346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
       [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
       [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
-----------------------
```

Here are the respective versions:

```
$ ssh -V  
OpenSSH_7.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

$ git --version  
git version 2.16.2.windows.1

$ git-review --version  
git-review version 1.26.0
```

Comment: `scp -P gerrit@9.126.191.111:hooks/commit-msg .git/hooks/commit-msg` you are missing the port, that's why you are getting the error

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit@9.126.191.111
```

Here gerrit is the username of an account registered in your gerrit service, with which you can log into the gerrit web. It is to run gerrit commands from your local machine, for example `ssh -p 29418 gerrit@9.126.191.111 gerrit query status:merged` to query all the changes that have been merged. First your account username may not be gerrit, but more likely is your real name or job number. Second, no matter what the username is, before you can use the username to invoke gerrit commands, you need to generate a pair of ssh keys and add the ssh public key to the username's account settings in the gerrit web.

```
ssh gerrit@9.126.191.111
```

This gerrit is the username with which you remotely log into the machine 9.125.191.111. This command does not have anything to do with the gerrit service.

Comment: Yes, I have created a common username called gerrit under which I have setup the gerrit (for ex., here's the path to the gerrit config file: /home/gerrit/gerrit_site/etc/gerrit.config).  

I have already setup ssh under gerrit username:  
    `$ pwd :  
    /home/gerrit/.ssh 
    $ ls : 
    authorized_keys id_rsa id_rsa.pub `

And copied the public key of my desktop to my linux server: 
    `ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub gerrit@9.125.191.111`

Comment: @Chhatrapati copy the content of the public key, log into the gerrit web with a username, foo for example, and then click the username in the top right corner of the web, click Settings -> SSH Public Keys -> Add Key -> paste the key content and press Add. Afterwards, you can run `ssh -p 29418 foo@9.126.191.111`.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! It never occured to me that I needed to do anything on the browser. I thought I can get away doing everything on the command line. Thank you.

Comment: @Chhatrapati You are welcome. Glad it helps. These two ssh commands are doing different jobs and the 2 "gerrit" are not the same. And you can add the key via the commands, with gerrit restapi and curl.